# VMWare VM to AWS / Azure migration

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, vmware, server-migration

We have 50+ VM's (Windows and Linux) running in on-prem VMWare environment. We want to migrate (lift and shift) all the VM's to public cloud like AWS/Azure. Is there any open source tools/framework which will help to speed up the migration rather doing things completely manual? Any suggestions and idea will help us lot.

Answer (score 0):

To migrate VMs to AWS you can use AWS Server Migration Service. With it you can replicate your vms to AMIs and then run them on EC2. You can find documentation here: https://aws.amazon.com/server-migration-service/